# set screw needed - do not know model

Tags: lock

I need to replace the set screw on the inside lever of a kwikset door lock. I do not know the model number. How can I determine the size screw I will require?

Answer (score 1):

Take the lever to a hardware store that has bins of various sized bolts. Figure the size, then get a grub screw to suit. My gut tells me you should start in the imperial section, rather than metric.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that a couple of times. All the screws of near size were in plastic packaging hard to gauge proper fit. Thought I'd throw this against the wall and see if anyone had an easy answer. Will try again.

Comment: talk to the store staff

Comment: Often there are drawers of machine screws, one of which likely has the same diameter and thread pitch as your needed set screw. Try them until you find the right one.

Comment: Then you're in the wrong kind of store.  You need the kind of store where all the bolts are loose in bins or drawers, and they have little bags you put your bolts in and have a space to write quantity and price.  Typically a real hardware store rather than a big-box store.